# What does "ad-hoc" mean?

Tags: adjectives, meaning-in-context

I read some articles that used *ad-hoc* like an adjective.

Questions:

1. What exactly does it mean in this paragraph:

> Needless to say, all of that is pretty painful and error prone.  Sure, once you’re familiar with a library, you’d probably just copy it from another project instead of getting it from the web, which makes things a bit easier.  But it’s still an overall very **ad-hoc** process.
>
> [Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20150911230738/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/davidebb/archive/2010/10/05/introducing-nupack-the-smart-way-to-bring-bits-into-your-projects.aspx).

2. Are there any other meanings?

Comment: No one has actually said that yet, so I'll comment here: ***ad hoc*** (like the other Latin locutions) should not be hyphenated, whether it's used as an adverb or adjectivally.

Comment: It would help if you look in a dictionary and then tell us what you do not understand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Ad hoc* means (as reported by the OED) "created or done for a particular purpose as necessary."

> The discussions were on an ad hoc basis.
>   The group was constituted ad hoc.

The NOAD gives a similar definition: "formed, arranged, or done for a particular purpose only."
The *Collins English Dictionary* defines *ad hoc* as "for a particular purpose only; lacking generality or justification."

> an ad hoc decision
>   an ad hoc committee

The phrase comes from Latin, and it literally means "to this."

Comment: There may also be an implication of the ad hoc thing being temporary or last-minute in nature. See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc).

Comment: It's usually synonymous with "on the fly" or "off the cuff." Sometimes means "as needed." In other words, "not planned in advance."

Answer (score 3):

made or happening only for a particular purpose or need, not planned before it happens

> ad hoc committee/meeting
>
> We deal with problems on an ad hoc basis (= as they happen).

Answer (score 1):

Ad-hoc means that the solution is designed for this singular purpose, and not meant to be adapted to other processes.